# How do you position CSS elements directly under each other?

Tags: html, css, position

I know there is probably a solved question like this, but I've searched and I couldn't a solution.

So, look. I have the basics for a website. A header, featured content, main content, and footer. I want the main content to fall under the featured content, but right now it's behind it. How can I make it go right underneath it?

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navigation"></div>
    <div class="content-featured"></div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body { 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
}

.navigation {
float: left;
padding: 15px 0;
min-width: 100%;
opacity: .48; /* layer alpha */
background-color: #1f1f1f; /* layer fill content */
height: 20px;
}

.content-featured {
height: 384px;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom left, #1db568 -25%, #1db568 17.74%, #257755 125%); /* gradient overlay */
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom left, #1db568 -25%, #1db568 17.74%, #257755 125%); /* gradient overlay */
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom left, #1db568 -25%, #1db568 17.74%, #257755 125%); /* gradient overlay */
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom left, #1db568 -25%, #1db568 17.74%, #257755 125%); /* gradient overlay */
}

.content-main {
height: 308px;
}
```

Comment: Please post what you have so far...

Comment: Can you provide your code here? The answer could be to clear both, fix the float etc etc.Need to see your code though to be more specific (HTML and CSS)

Comment: Sorry for no code. Post updated.

Comment: Post the rest of you HTML...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a container div. This holds everything you want, whether you want to stack them vertically or horizontally. So roughly it would look like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="header">
    </div>

    <div class="navigation">
    </div>

    <div class="left-sidebar">
    </div>

    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

And your CSS would be

```
#container {
width:960px;
}
.header, .navigation {
width: 100%;
float:left;
height: 80px;
}
.sidebar {
width: 200px;
float:left;
min-height: 500px;
}
.content {
width: 760px;
float: left;
min-height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! But, instead of making a new container, I just added the CSS to the body container. Would I run into any problems in the future?

Comment: Nope that works too, but generally being more specific is better, because having the layers of <html> then <body> then an actual container providers more flexibility!! :)

Comment: Why did you float the `width:100%` elements? @IntactDev, it's pretty standard to have an explicit "container" that you manipulate within the body.

Comment: @trojansdestroy You're right, no need to float everything--force of habit I guess.